# Views in different tabs show the same data

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

So I'm trying to have different views in a tab control. It can be many tabs with the same type of viewmodel but they all have different data.

I pick the view depending on the view model type:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenTabs}">
            <style>
               a lot of style code....
            </style>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type designView:TestcaseViewModel}">
                <Views:DesignView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type returnView:ReturnViewModel}">
                <Views:ReturnView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

To test the code I add a couple of different viewmodels in my constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _projectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = _projectViewModel;
        _projectViewModel.OpenTabs.Add(new TestcaseViewModel("test"));
        _projectViewModel.OpenTabs.Add(new TestcaseViewModel("My second test"));
        _projectViewModel.OpenTabs.Add(new TestcaseViewModel("Another test")); 
    }
```

I now see three different tabs (with different headers) and they work. Except that they all show the same data and if I change anything in one of them it happen on all the others. So I guess all views share the same view model or something? How do I make it so when I click on a new tab the view in that tab also use the corresponding view model?

Comment: Interesting, there is nothing obviously wrong there. What happens when you add a view model of a different type ie a ReturnViewModel? Similarly, if you have multiple ReturnViewModels do they exhibit the same problem?

Comment: As said, there is nothing wrong what you're doing right now. It's standard approach, and should work - you can validate it yourself, create a new simple test project. I suspect if you remove your `Style`, it should work, unless something else is interfering.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried to remove the style but didn't fix it. But I saw another funny thing. If I added a ReturnViewModel too, and jumped between the tabs, the data would be removed. 

So for example, if I was on a design tab and changed some data. Then changed to a result tub and back, all my changed would be gone. Really strange.